# Dynamically toggle swipeEnabled on MaterialTopTabNavigator in React Native

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I'm using the Material Top Tab Navigator from React Native Navigation, created with `createMaterialTopTabNavigator()`. As per the documentation, this function accepts a `TabNavigatorConfig` object as the second argument, which has a property `swipeEnabled` determining if you should be able to swipe between the different tabs.

The issue is, I normally want the swipe behavior enabled, but only want to disable it under certain circumstances. Is there a way to toggle this between `true` and `false` dynamically once a certain event is triggered in one of the tabs?

Answer (score -1):

You need to use React Navigation 5 (currently alpha) for dynamic configuration:

https://next.reactnavigation.org/

Comment: I'm using React Navigation v5 and still can't dynamically update the swipeEnabled prop.
Seems like the configuration is static.